Do different models of ZFC affect the well-ordering of natural numbers?
I’ve heard that the axioms of ZFC admit various models. To be honest, I’m not entirely sure what a model is, and I apologize if I’m using terms loosely here.
From what I understand, the axiom of infinity says "an inductive set exists," and the set of natural numbers $\omega$ is the intersection of all inductive sets. I’ve also read that, within first-order logic, it’s not possible to state that $\omega$ contains only $\emptyset$ and its successors. I’m considering a case where every inductive set also contains something like $\{\{\emptyset\}\}$, for example.
In such a scenario, would facts like the well-ordering of the natural numbers still hold, or would these extra elements change things?
Also, how do we determine which model of ZFC is "favored," and what makes certain models more legitimate than others?
Edit: this is not a duplicate of Any well-ordered set must be inductive? because it essentially asks the converse of that one and has a broader scope.

Regarding the “favored” model of ZFC, you might want to read about the cumulative hierarchy.

It's worth noting that models of set theory have a fundamentally different "sociological" status to, say, the models of the group axioms (i.e. groups). The point of group theory is to study these models, and essentially no group theorist proves their theorems by proving first-order statements in the language of group theory. By contrast, when we are using set theory as a foundational system, the reverse is true: one wants to reduce ordinary mathematical proofs to symbolic manipulations in the first-order language of set theory, and rarely do we need to consider models of set theory.

Perhaps reading this answer on MathOverflow would help. But in any case, models of set theory can be extremely confusing, and it might be best to avoid thinking about them until you have studied more set theory and logic. (I might be able to write a longer answer later.)

You asked:

"Do different models of ZFC affect the well-ordering of natural
numbers?"

No, because the well-ordering property of $\mathbb N$ is a theorem of
of the theory ZFC.  Therefore it holds in any model of ZFC.

"In such a scenario, would facts like the well-ordering of the
natural numbers still hold, or would these extra elements change
things?"

The possible "extra elements" do not change the well-ordering property
(WOP) of $\mathbb N$, defined as you point out as the least inductive
set.  This may seem puzzling at first.  Thus, if $H$ is an element
greater than each naive counting number such as $1,2,3$, then
apparently $H-1$, $H-2$, $H-3$ will still be greater than $1,2,3$,
which would seem to be at odds with the WOP.  The point is that if we
are in a model $M$ of ZFC, there will be no set in the model which
violates the WOP.  On the other hand, "the natural numbers" $\mathbb
N_M$ of the model might be an extension of the $\mathbb N_m$ of a
smaller model $m$ (via for example an ultrapower construction).
From this point of view, $\mathbb N_M$ will contain sets which are
external as far as the model $M$ is concerned, and "invisible" when
the axioms of ZFC are interpreted in relation to the model $M$ (rather
than to $m$).  In particular, the larger "natural numbers" will satisfy WOP
when interpreted in the model.

"Also, how do we determine which model of ZFC is "favored," and what
makes certain models more legitimate than others?"

This already is a matter of philosophical interpretation, and a
subject of dispute among various schools of thought in the philosophy
of mathematics.  Platonists believe in the existence of a preferred
model which they refer to as the "standard model" or "the intended
intepretation".
On the other hand, Formalists reject the existence of such a preferred
model when dealing with infinite sets.  Thus, Abraham Robinson wrote:

"In particular, I will mention here the assumption that there exists
a standard or intended model of Arithmetic or (alternatively, but
relatedly) of Set Theory.  Clearly, to the formalist, the entire
notion of standardness must be meaningless, In accordance with our
first basic principle."  (Robinson in Formalism 64 - published in
1965 - page 242).

As far as most (though not all) of the undergraduate curriculum is
concerned, it does not matter which model you are in, and whether or
not you believe in the existence of a standard one.  Beyond that, the
comparison with group theory is quite apt.  For example, to do
infinitesimal analysis (i.e., analysis with infinitesimals) it is
useful to think of such a pair of models $m$ and $M$. Infinitesimals
and infinite (more precisely, unlimited) numbers will be found in such
an extension.

Let $A$ be an inductive set. If a property like the (recursive) $P(x)\equiv (x=\emptyset )\lor\exists y(y\in A\land P(y)\land x=y\cup {y})$ is valid to be used as in $I={x\in A|P(x)}$, $\mathbb N_M$ would not contain such "garbage" and the following argument should be disregarded. Otherwise, suppose $c={{\emptyset}}$ is a minimal element in $\mathbb N_M$. Why the Induction Principle still holds? Assuming (a) $Q(0)$ and (b) for all $n\in \mathbb N_M$, $Q(n)$ implies $Q(n+1)$, I can’t see how $Q$ holds for all natural numbers $n$ (in particular for $c$ and its successors).

There are two famous definitions of the natural numbers within ZFC, due to Zermelo and von Neumann.  Zermelo indeed used the simplest scheme $\varnothing, {\varnothing}, {{\varnothing}}$ etc.  Von Neumann used ${\varnothing,{\varnothing}}$ (a philosopher named Benacerraf commented extensively on this).  Von Neumann's scheme is a bit more convenient because the membership relation naturally becomes the order relation on $\mathbb N$.  At any rate, if you use von Neumann's scheme for the successor, then ${{\varnothing}}$ does not arise. @materia

I see. I just meant to provide an example of a non standard element whose presence in every inductive set could not be ruled out by means of the axioms of ZFC. The way I see it, and there I’m probably wrong, a “clean” $\mathbb N$ is conveniently chosen at will.

The specific element ${{\varnothing}}$ as far as I can tell is not present in any inductive set in the von Neumann scheme of things, because that's not how the successor is defined according to von Neumann.

Is there a way to prove it?

The construction of the successor produces $\varnothing, {\varnothing}, {\varnothing,{\varnothing}}$, etc.  All of the other ones have more curly braces than ${{\varnothing}}$.  Thus it does not occur in the construction of the successor.
